# CM made an edit which is not showing up in the timeline?

Tags: bug

**On the landing page it says that Catija has modified this question:**

[image]

**But the timeline on the question doesn't show what modification that was:**

[image]

I've never seen that before. Is it a [bug](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a now-deleted answer on that question which didn't really answer the question. I assume she edited it before it was deleted.

Comment: Catija edited the answer, but it was a self-delete.

Comment: @JNat thanks for checking!

Comment: @JNat Since none of us can see the deleted answer except for CMs and Glorfindel, I wonder if it has something to do with [this user](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/67/adatainment?tab=reputation) having a reputation of 2 including the 1-point default that everyone has. This means they gained a net reputation of 1. Perhaps this can happen by editing a post (+1) and then downvoting an answer once (-1), but the user has never downvoted. If a user never downvotes, how can they gain a reputation of "only 1" ?

Comment: @NikeDattani FWIW I can't see the answer now either.

Comment: I thought deleted answers on one's own question are still visible, but I could be wrong (perhaps you need more rep). Do you have any idea why that user (from my last comment) had a reputation of 2? It seems it's been decreased back down to 1, but with no history of how it changed. Perhaps @JNat could shed some light on it?

Comment: @NikeDattani that user now has 1 reputation; also, they weren't involved in this situation.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yea I noticed it's now 1, but it certainly said 2 when I wrote the first comment. It was very bizarre.

Comment: That user has nothing to do with any of this, @NikeDattani. Catija edited the answer, and it got bumped on the homepage; the author of the answer then deleted it. That's all there is to it. As per [this page](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), "the post's author, developers, moderators, and users with over 1,000 reputation" can see deleted posts, and no one else can — hence why you can't.